# Как должны правильно взаимодействовать модель и QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Приветствую! 
Ситуация следующая:
Есть моделька, основанная на `QAbstractItemMode`l, так как данных достаточно много, получаю их с помощью предназначенного для этого `canFetchMore` и `fetchMore`
и когда просто модель отображается в `ListView` (qml), всё замечательно, данные подгружаются по мере пролистывания.

Теперь на эту модельку сверху вешаю прокси, на основе `QSortFilterProxyModel`
в ней для теста отбираю строки (переопределив `filterAcceptsRow`) по какому нибудь полю, не важно.

Дальше начинаются проблемы. 
При установленной фильтрации во вьюшке выводятся не все возможные значения!
т.е. выводятся только загруженные в `fetchMore` в данный момент. 
Т.е. в `fetchMore` гружу по 100 записей, не выводятся ни одной, т.к. целевые значения будут прогружены начиная с 500.
и прогрузки дальше не происходит т.к. логично, что вьюшка не считает необходимым загружать ещё т.к. всё умещается и не надо пролистывать но и прокси моделька не считает нужным прогрузить дальше, либо как-то сообщить основной модели - мне нужны записи с вот такими значениями.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть? 
Не, я согласен, что лучше всего будет выбирать нужные значение через запрос к базе, что бы не грузить лишнего,
но как тогда лучше сделать связь с основной моделью?

т.е. например я в `fetchRow` основной модели прогрузил записи от 0 до 100, в прокси модели нужно выбирать, которые располагаются начиная с 500, ок, я говорю основной модели - прогрузи ка записи с вот такими значенияи, если есть.
Ок, гружу.

Но возникает следующая проблема - если запись например 555 добавлена в модель, то при скролинге вьюшки, она попросит записи с 500 по 600 и я тогда снова добавлю запись 555. т.е. получается будет дублирование. 
Запоминать записи, которые грузил? что-то костылём попахивает. 
Может есть красивый выход из ситуации?

Спасибо, даже за подсказки, на что смотреть!

Comment: Без `fetchMore` работает?

Comment: Для сортировки и фильтрации в любом случае требуется весь набор данных. Поэтому динамически исходные данные подгружать без кэширования или других костылей, не получится. К стати этот вопрос уже задавался на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348735/qt-models-behind-proxies-and-fetchmore-canfetchmore

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, тут может быть только три варианта для решения проблемы.

Первый - самый бестолковый, если данных очень много. Предполагает, что модель-источник должна загрузить сразу все данные и не использовать `fetchMore` в принципе.

Второе решение может быть основано на переопределении метода `fetchMore()` у прокси с тем условием, что будет сразу же (рекурсивно) повторять запрос на чтение новых строк из исходной модели до тех пор, пока количество строк в прокси после `filterAcceptsRow()` не достигнет нужного числа, либо исходная модель не прочитает все данные. Фактически, это решение почти столь же бестолковое, что и первое, так как потребуется полное считывание всех данных исходной модели при определённых условиях фильтрации.

Третье решение предполагает использование фильтрации данных непосредственно в модели-источнике. Обратите внимание, что все SQL-модели из состава Qt имеют возможность фильтровать данные самостоятельно и в общем случае не нуждаются в каких-либо прокси. Если модель-источник является таблицей в БД, то имеет смысл использовать классы, специально предназначенные для работы с подобными источниками, а не заниматься наследованием абстрактной модели. Если же модель-источник не является таблицей в БД, а, например, представляет из себя некий файл, то фильтрация данных должна быть добавлена в эту исходную модель и производиться непосредственно при вызове `fetchMore()` с тем, чтобы выдать минимальное количество данных, соответствующих условиям фильтрации.